# US Congress Members by zipcode API

Tags: api, zipcode

I need to get all congress members of an area by giving a Zipcode in one of my web portal. Do anyone has idea on the API's available so far. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: https://developers.google.com/civic-information/ I've been using this data for our small project. Its pretty simple to work with. Good luck!